# How do I fix my laptop screen from being blank until the computer warms up?

Tags: boot

My new (just three days old) Dell Inspiron N4050's screen isn't working.  When I press the power button, the fans start running, and I hear sounds related to logging in, but the screen remains blank.  After about 45 minutes, the screen will turn on, and act normally.  If I reboot the computer, it continues working, but if I turn the computer off and let it cool off, the same thing will happen.  I've noticed that when the laptop heats up, it shows everything, but upon cooling, the screen remains blank.

How do I fix this?

Comment: This sounds like a hardware problem, especially if you can't even see the initial boot messages.

Comment: Definitely a hardware problem. Contact dell

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a hardware problem with the backlight or inverter.  Since you're still under warranty, contact Dell and have them fix it.

If you're reading this question as someone whose laptop is not still under warranty, check out https://superuser.com/q/164058/16133 for more details on potential fixes.