# Dim (NEARLY blank) laptop screen, secondary screen works - why?

Tags: 10.04, backlight

My laptop screen is (almost) black while my secondary screen is fine. I believe it to be backlight / brightness related.

### Problem description

- it starts when I start the laptop
- system loads and works fine, just screen has problems
- I *can* see the screen though very faintly / dimly - it's hard to see anything which ain't very white e.g. starting screen has big Thinkpad logo in white, large font - I can see it, though very dimly
- second screen works very well

[Official backligtht debugging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/Debugging/Backlight):

- using acpi setting as prescribed there for Thinkpads didn't help
- I can see an entry in `/sys/class/backlight/` and it changes when I press hotkeys for brightness (current backlight power for instance goes up or down)
- `acpi-off` didn't helpm neither did `acpi_backlight=vendor`

### Hardware data

Laptop is Thinkpad Edge with glossy screen. 4 processors, 2 cores, exemplary CPU data from `cat /proc/cpuinfo` reports Genuine Intel i5 (M 480  @ 2.67GHz).

OS is Ubuntu Lucid, 10.04 LTS, *64-bit*, with Linux generic kernel (2.6.32-44) and GNOME 2.32.2 (though I doubt there lies the problem).

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series]

$ lshw -C display
*-display               
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: M92 [Mobility Radeon HD 4500 Series]
   vendor: ATI Technologies Inc
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
   resources: irq:33 memory:c0000000-dfffffff(prefetchable) ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f0300000-f030ffff memory:f0320000-f033ffff(prefetchable)
```

### Driver

I was NOT running any proprietary drivers, just checked with "Hardware drivers". There is one for ATI that is suggested there, though I didn't need it so far.

UPDATE: changing the driver to proprietary one (ATI/AMD FGLRX) didn't help.

### Tried and failed

Resetting / running on power or battery / charging / [getting rid of static electricity](http://www.ehow.com/how_4560492_fix-laptop-black-screen.html) / [warming up](https://askubuntu.com/questions/118134/how-do-i-fix-my-laptop-screen-from-being-blank-until-the-computer-warms-up) *_doesn't help_*

This is *NOT* a blank-screen problem, at least it isn't [following official Ubuntu black-screen diagnostics](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/BlankScreen) - I can see my screen, though barely.

What I will try next:
    - check last updates I've made
    - IIRC I am running on nomodeset already, but will verify this

Any ideas how to proceed best? What is most probable cause?

Comment: What happens if you disconnect the secondary screen ?

Comment: Thanks, Suhaib. Unfortunately - nothing. I just lose a screen that displays things well. No change on laptop screen - it stays near-black as it was. I plugged other monitor to see if it's a graphics problem or just my laptop screen problem - originally I worked only on my laptop, without secondary monitor.

Comment: please provide some details on your system: platform type (desktop / laptop), computer model, graphics card and drivers installed etc., in addition, it may help to see the output of `lshw -C display`.

Comment: Thanks Eliran for spotting this. Certainly. I've edited my question with both hardware/driver data and with my new findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the end it was a backlight problem.** What led me to it, was that if I had a strong light source pointed at the screen - I could see well what was on it.

I took the laptop to service and it was fixed - backlight connection was loose.